# Find value associated with min value of another col with a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, correlated-subquery

Say I have a table of prices;

```
+------------+----------+---+-----+----+-------+-----+
| product_id | price_id | a |  b  | c  | price | fee |
+------------+----------+---+-----+----+-------+-----+
|          1 |        1 | 1 | 100 | 10 |   500 |  60 |
|          1 |        2 | 1 | 100 | 20 |   505 |  50 |
|          1 |        3 | 1 | 200 | 10 |   510 |  30 |
|          1 |        4 | 1 | 200 | 20 |   515 |  25 |
|          1 |        5 | 1 | 300 | 10 |   520 |  15 |
|          1 |        6 | 1 | 300 | 20 |   525 |  50 |
|          1 |        7 | 2 | 100 | 10 |   530 |  40 |
|          1 |        8 | 2 | 100 | 20 |   535 |  35 |
|          1 |        9 | 2 | 200 | 10 |   540 |  60 |
+------------+----------+---+-----+----+-------+-----+
```

In reality this table would have hundreds of products and each of columns a, b, and c could take up around 10 values and there would be a price for every combination of these columns for each product.

I only want to display 1 price per product, so I have a `GROUP BY` on product_id.

Say I initially want to display the lowest price for each product, I can achieve this by `SELECT` min(price), no problem. Now, when I want to show the fee relating to the min price, I can't just show min(fee) because the prices and fees don't correlate and the minimum price does not necessarily have the lowest fee. So I join on a subquery, like so;

```
SELECT
    t.product_id,
    t.price_id,
    t.a,
    t.b, 
    t.c, 
    min(t.price) as `min_price`,
    t.fee,
    t2.fee AS `min_price_fee`
FROM
    prices as t
JOIN so_q as t2 on t.product_id = t2.product_id
    AND t.a = t2.a
    AND t.b = t2.b
    AND t.c = t2.c
    AND t2.price = (
        SELECT min(price)
        FROM so_q as t3 
        WHERE t3.product_id = t.product_id
--          AND t3.b = 300
    )
-- WHERE
--  t.b = 300
GROUP BY
    t.product_id;
```

But as you might have guessed from the lines I've commented out, my problem comes when users have added filters and there's now a where clause in play. I can't make this work without also putting the where clause in to the subquery, (if I don't I get no rows returned, which I think I understand) and my question is, is there a way I can do this so that I only have to have the where clause once?

Thanks for your advice - let me know if I should include any other info. Trying to distil an MCVE from the actual code I'm working with was complicated so I may have forgotten something obvious.

**EDIT** like MySQL version which is 5.5.56

**EDIT 2**

using @Gordon Linoff's suggestion;

```
SELECT
    p.* 
FROM
    prices p 
WHERE
    p.price = ( 
        SELECT min( p2.price )
        FROM prices p2
        WHERE p2.product_id = p.product_id
    )
AND b = 300;
```

I'm still getting 0 rows returned when I add the `b = 300` condition to the where clause on the last line.

**EDIT 3**

To try and clarify what I'm trying to do: before any filters are added, for product 1, I want to display the minimum price (500) and the fee (60) from that record (price_id = 1). If a user adds a filter stipulating `c = 20`, then I want to display the minimum price which has a `c` value of 20 (505) and the fee (50) from that record (price_id = 2). I don't think I can use `min(price)` *and* `min(fee)` because I will end up with prices and fees from different records and they must be from the same record. So, I need to find the minimum price which satisfies all the user entered criteria (which end up as parts of the main where clause) and then find the fee associated with that price.

Comment: I believe that there is no way to rewrite it without window functions or CTE in a way you request it. Unfortunately, lower versions of MySQL (less than 8) does not have it. Therefore, which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: sorry, edited to include, MySQL version 5.5.56. ah, so I maybe out of luck here...

Comment: What if the lowest prices don't ever occur when b is 300?  Then you don't want the lowest price for a product? You want the lowest price for a product where B = 300?  Please update your question with more exact explanation and use data examples to demonstrate what should or should not happen.

Comment: Correct, I want the lowest price which meets the criteria - hopefully update #3 clarifies this a little.

Comment: Then just add your filters to both where clauses in the answer from @GordonLinoff.

Comment: I realise that I can do that, my question is specifically, is it possible to achieve my aims without doing that, that is, only including the filters once.

Comment: And it's taken you this long to say that?  What you MUST do is ensure that the correlated sub query operates on the same data as the outer query. Either you add the filter twice, or you add an extra predicate such as `p2.b = p.b`.  The down side of the latter is that it must match whichever filters you use. If you filter on c, you also correlate on C.  Experiment with the answer given to you until you understand how it works. Then you might understand that there is no answer that allows filters in the outer query without also making changes to the correlated sub query.

Comment: Obviously I wasn't clear enough but I was trying to explain this desire in the last paragraph of my original question. I'm sorry it was ambiguous and I appreciate your help. I will experiment with the suggestion as you suggest. Also, your comment is the answer to my question. I don't have a good understand of correlated subqueries, so I asked if is was possible, the answer is no and I've learned something, so thank you.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to only have the filter in the correlated sub-query?  And is it ever possible for two records to be fitted for the same price? If so what do you need the query to do? Return all ties, or the tie with the lowest fee, or something else?

Comment: to be honest, the way the code is written that writes this query, probably not,  but for my own personal learning, I would love to see how that would work?

Comment: In on my phone. Use a sub-query like `p.id = (SELECT id FROM prices p2 WHERE p2.product_id = p.product_id AND <filters> ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1)`  This will always yield one row, even if multiple rows are equal on price. In such cases extend the ORDER BY to deterministically pick the one you want.

Comment: Also, it would be better to start with a product table...  `product INNER JOIN prices ON prices.id = (SELECT id FROM prices p2 WHERE p2.product_id = product.id AND <filters> ORDER BY p2.price DESC LIMIT 1)`  This is because there will be fewer rows being fed into the correlated subquery.

Comment: @MatBailie, thank you so much for this, it's been really helpful. Do you want to add an answer summarising and I'l accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @GordonLinoff's answer and extending the requirement to include minimising the the amount of code repetition, to make dynamic generation of the SQL simpler...

Changing the correlated sub-query to return a row identifier instead of a minimum price has two consequences

1. You only need to put the filter in the sub-query
2. It will never return multiple rows in the event of a tie

```
p.id = (SELECT id
          FROM prices p2
         WHERE p2.product_id = p.product_id
           AND <filters>
      ORDER BY price DESC,
               some_tie_break_field(s)
         LIMIT 1
       )
```

With such a structure, you would probably benefit from starting with a `product` table to minimise the work done by the correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT
  prices.*
FROM
  product
INNER JOIN
  prices
      ON prices.id = (SELECT id
                        FROM prices p
                       WHERE p.product_id = product.id
                         AND <filters>
                    ORDER BY price DESC,
                             some_tie_break_field(s)
                       LIMIT 1
                      )
```

Comment: Thanks very much @MatBailie, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `group by`.  You want to filter out all the other rows, so use `where`:

```
select p.*
from prices p
where p.price = (select min(p2.price)
                 from prices p2
                 where p2.product_id = p.product_id
                );
```

If you need to filter on `b`, then you need to take this into account in both the subquery and outer query:

```
select p.*
from prices p
where p.b = 300 and
      p.price = (select min(p2.price)
                 from prices p2
                 where p2.product_id = p.product_id and p2.b = p.b
                );
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I add `AND b = 300` to the `where`, then I still get 0 rows returned so unless I'm missing something I don't know if this solves my problem?

Comment: @sauntimo Update your question to include your actual attempt.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not quite sure what you mean by that - do you mean my attempt to use Gordon Linoff's suggestion?

Comment: @sauntimo Yes. They're are two where clauses, and many other mistakes you could make. If you want us to help you with a sql query, supply the Entire and Exact query you tried, don't make us guess.

Comment: ah, I've updated to include. Sorry, you make a really good point - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments, there are solutions using window function and CTE, however, those are not available in lower versions of MySQL. The only solution that I can propose where the constant does not repeat is the following:

```
SELECT
    t.product_id,
    t.price_id,
    t.a,
    t.b, 
    t.c, 
    min(t.price) as `min_price`,
    t.fee,
    t2.fee AS `min_price_fee`
FROM
    prices as t
JOIN so_q as t2 on t.product_id = t2.product_id
    AND t.a = t2.a
    AND t.b = t2.b
    AND t.c = t2.c
    AND t.b = 300
    AND t2.price = (
        SELECT min(price)
        FROM so_q as t3 
        WHERE t3.product_id = t.product_id  AND 
              t3.b = t.b
    )
```

Comment: Based on the OP comments, this could be misunderstood. If the user removes the filter `b = 300` then the `t3.b = t.b` MUST also be removed. Its easiest to simply state that any user filters must be applied both inside the sub query and outside of it too.